# Edit options disappeared on reload of tableview ios 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I am working on iOS 8 beta version. I have a tableview in edit mode with delete and reordering options. These edit options works fine for the first time, but as the table gets reloaded or cell gets reloaded(On table scroll) theses options disappears.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Update: 
The following method of UITableViewCell does gives editing as "YES" every time

(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated

I have a check inside this method

if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) rangeOfString: @"Reorder"].location != NSNotFound)

which seems to be working when the table is created for the first time, but does not work when table gets reloaded.

Comment: iOS 8 is still under nda?

Comment: As per http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/ Apple has partially lifted nda.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that these two function are returning the values shown. otherwise even in editing mode it will appear as if it "Not" in editing mode.

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete; 
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return YES;
}
```